# Different browser's behaving in different way for same script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am facing some strange behavior of different browser.i have fallowing condition in my javascript which is working fine in Mozilla and chrome but not in IE.

```
if(sValue.indexOf('<br>')!=-1){
 // do something
}
```

when i changed my code in fallowing way , then it's working fine in IE but not in Mozilla and chrome.

```
if(sValue.indexOf('<BR>')!=-1){
 // do something
}
```

anybody knows why it's happening like this?.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that you are getting the browser to serialize the DOM to HTML to get the value for `sValue`. HTML is case insensitive, so browsers are free to use whatever case they like for tag names.

The solution is `String.toLowerCase()`

Comment: thanks David..i should try this before posting the question...any way thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
if((sValue.toLowerCase()).indexOf('<br>')!=-1){
 // do something
}
```

or

```
sValue=sValue.toLowerCase();
if(sValue.indexOf('<br>')!=-1){
 // do something
}
```